UUID changed && Droping to shell
Help a linux beginner!!
Last thing I did on my ubuntu was trying to uninstall Wine and trying to pass a few files to my external drive. I might have fucked up some partition while doing that, but smt very odd is happening.
When I try to boot, it goes to BusyBox. If I try to exit, it gives me:
(initramfs) exit Gave up waiting for root file system device. Common problems:

⁃ Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline) Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)

⁃ Hissing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)

ALERT! UUID= XXXXXXXXXXX does not exist. Dropping to shell

(Censored my UUID cause it seems to be a sensitive info. Idk)
And when I go to my bios, something even weirder happens: the serial number, asset tag number product name, manufacturer name and UUID have changed! Now they are:
Serial Number:  4444444444444444444444 

Asset Tag Number:4444444444444444444444 

Product Name: 44444444444444444444444444444444

Manufacturer Name: 444444444444444 

UUID:34343434-3434-3434-3434-343434343434

I just plugged a live Ubuntu on pendrive and I'm trying to troubleshoot it now.
blkid gives me:
/dev/loop1: BLOCK_SIZE="131072" TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop2: BLOCK_SIZE="131072" TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/loop0: BLOCK_SIZE="131072" TYPE="squashfs"
/dev/mapper/ventoy: BLOCK_SIZE="2048" UUID="2024-04-24-11-29-09-00" LABEL="Ubuntu 24.04 LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="1cf7d054-8db5-4194-971e-3c8665684807" PTTYPE="gpt"
/dev/sda1: LABEL="Ventoy" UUID="DB7B-A845" BLOCK_SIZE="512" TYPE="exfat" PARTLABEL="Ventoy" PARTUUID="76e872ae-bb81-48f6-929b-1de102ff0dd8"
/dev/sda2: BLOCK_SIZE="2048" UUID="2024-04-24-11-29-09-00" LABEL="Ubuntu 24.04 LTS amd64" TYPE="iso9660" PTUUID="1cf7d054-8db5-4194-971e-3c8665684807" PTTYPE="gpt"

fdisk -l gives me:
    Disk /dev/loop0: 1.63 GiB, 1748217856 bytes, 3414488 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop1: 457.53 MiB, 479752192 bytes, 937016 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop2: 868.06 MiB, 910225408 bytes, 1777784 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop3: 4 KiB, 4096 bytes, 8 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop4: 74.24 MiB, 77844480 bytes, 152040 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop5: 269.63 MiB, 282722304 bytes, 552192 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop6: 10.72 MiB, 11239424 bytes, 21952 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop7: 505.09 MiB, 529625088 bytes, 1034424 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/sda: 14.32 GiB, 15376318464 bytes, 30031872 sectors
Disk model: Cruzer Blade    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E2F8E1EC-5B3D-4533-8CB3-28FE689FB563

Device        Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1      2048 29966295 29964248 14.3G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda2  29966296 30031831    65536   32M Microsoft basic data
The backup GPT table is corrupt, but the primary appears OK, so that will be used.


Disk /dev/mapper/ventoy: 5.69 GiB, 6114656256 bytes, 11942688 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 1CF7D054-8DB5-4194-971E-3C8665684807

Device                      Start      End  Sectors  Size Type
/dev/mapper/ventoy-part1       64 11931883 11931820  5.7G Microsoft basic data
/dev/mapper/ventoy-part2 11931884 11942023    10140    5M EFI System
/dev/mapper/ventoy-part3 11942024 11942623      600  300K Microsoft basic data


Disk /dev/loop8: 137.29 MiB, 143962112 bytes, 281176 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop9: 116.72 MiB, 122392576 bytes, 239048 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop11: 38.73 MiB, 40615936 bytes, 79328 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop10: 91.69 MiB, 96141312 bytes, 187776 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop12: 10.32 MiB, 10821632 bytes, 21136 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes


Disk /dev/loop13: 476 KiB, 487424 bytes, 952 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes

cat /etc/fstab gives me:
overlay / overlay rw 0 0
tmpfs /tmp tmpfs nosuid,nodev 0 0

Yeah, I think I really fucked up my partitions.
Any thoughts?? I don't really know what to do ;-;

Did you somehow change the UUID of your root partition/external drive when you did something to configure wine? Was the external drive set to auto mount?

I was just trying to uninstall wine, not necessarily configure it. However, I use the software "disks" to unmount the external drive. I think I may have clicked to unmout the ssd instead or done smt weird with its partitions.

As it turns out, the answer was really simple: change from RAID to AHCI in your BIOS.
The trick was that I had to press ctrl + S so my BIOS would show me the option. After that, it worked like a charm.
